# How to Add Marker Using Overlay on Google Map In Android?

Tags: android

I want To add Marker on Google Maps using Overlay in Android...My code is below

```
@Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
            long when) {
          Point screenPts = new Point(); mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p1,
          screenPts);
          //---add the marker--- 
          Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources()
          , R.drawable.googlepin); ``
          canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x,
          screenPts.y-50, null);
                  }
        return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
    }
```

Give RedLine under getResources() ....Give Any Suggest.....Thanks In advance..